# AutoLayout Visual language for mixed V+H

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

How can view layouts such as this, where the subviews are in vertical and horizontal relationships, be described using the Visual language?

[image]

Comment: What are the desired horizontal / vertical relationships? Equal width ratio and constant margins? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, the frames and margins of the object will be changed at runtime, but fixed when entered into the visualFormat string.

Comment: I meant, if your screen were e.g. twice the size of what you posted what should the layout look like? All dimensions proportionate to screen size? Fixed margins? Flexible margins? Fixed widths? etc..

Comment: Im using autolayout just for the positioning, no scaling or flexible space. Everything fixed as I have predefined frame sizes that the views are created with. I would like to apply constraints to a number of fixed sized views that already know their frames and are positioned in the parent view. Im using autolayout for handling when items are added or removed, resized etc. The visual format string will always use fixed values to tie elements together if that makes sense. (iPad only, so no other screen sizes)

Comment: Well, one uses AutoLayout to handle some dynamic behaviour (adding removing / resizing in your case). I think you need to define supported actions for anyone to be able to help you with AutoLayout constraints.

Comment: check it this tutorial http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/26/the-swift-swift-tutorial-how-to-use-uiviews-with-auto-layout-programmatically/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is *one* way to do it. Assumptions: views 1 and 2 have a fixed pixel width, view 3 fills remaining width, fixed margin all round and between views. Views 1 and 2 equal height.

If those are wrong assumptions its pretty straightforward to extend this example.

Swift:

```
    let views = ["view1": view1, "view2": view2, "view3": view3]
    let metrics = ["m":12,"w":100]

    let format0 = "H:|-(m)-[view1(w)]-(m)-[view3]-(m)-|"
    let format1 = "H:|-(m)-[view2(w)]-(m)-[view3]-(m)-|"

    let format2 = "V:|-(m)-[view1]-(m)-[view2(==view1)]-(m)-|"
    let format3 = "V:|-(m)-[view3]-(m)-|"

    for  string in [format0,format1,format2,format3] as [String] {
        self.view.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                string,
                options:nil,
                metrics:metrics,
                views:views))
    }
```

Objective-C:

```
    NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1,view2,view3);
    NSDictionary* metrics = @{@"m":@(12),@"w":@(100)};

    NSString* format0 = @"H:|-m-[view1(w)]-m-[view3]-m-|";
    NSString* format1 = @"H:|-m-[view2(w)]-m-[view3]-m-|";

    NSString* format2 = @"V:|-m-[view1]-m-[view2(==view1)]-m-|";
    NSString* format3 = @"V:|-m-[view3]-m-|";

    for (NSString* string in @[format0,format1,format2,format3]) {
        [self.view addConstraints:
        [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:string 
                                                options:0 
                                                metrics:metrics
                                                  views:views]];
    }
```

The views under autolayout control need to have their `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property set to `NO` (it defaults to `YES`).

In one of your comments you say that the views 'already know their frames'. This sounds a little confused: when using autolayout, views don't set frames, frames are the result of the autolayout equations (the autolayout mechanism sets them).

In any case whether or not you use autolayout, views shouldn't set their own frames, that should be the job of the view's superview context. The superview, or its viewController would make frame decisions, as a frame positions a view with respect to the superview.

It sounds like you may mean that the views already know their *sizes*, based on their content (in the same way that buttons and labels know their sizes). In this case they can return a size value by overriding `-(CGSize) intrinsicContentSize` in a UIView subclass. Then you can then omit size metrics from the format strings, simplifying them to:

Swift:

```
let format0 = "H:|-m-[view1]-m-[view3]-m-|"
let format1 = "H:|-m-[view2]-m-[view3]-m-|"
let format2 = "V:|-m-[view1]-m-[view2]-m-|"
let format3 = "V:|-m-[view3]-m-|"
```

Objective-C:

```
NSString* format0 = @"H:|-m-[view1]-m-[view3]-m-|";
NSString* format1 = @"H:|-m-[view2]-m-[view3]-m-|";
NSString* format2 = @"V:|-m-[view1]-m-[view2]-m-|";
NSString* format3 = @"V:|-m-[view3]-m-|";
```

*However* if the sizes don't all add up (eg 3*m + view1.height + view2.height != superview.height) something's going to break, and you are losing the advantage of using autolayout to flexibly arrange your views to fill the available space.

Comment: Thanks for the great example. Regarding the sizes adding up, how would overflow be handled? e.g. if the view above gets another view added to it and one of the views results in an out of bounds or intersection with the superview frame? Where in the sequence of events will this take place? Should all the current constraints be removed, the new view added, all the constraints recalculated and applied, then look for overflow, frame intersection with superview, remove constraints linked to that view and remove that view from the superview, then run the layoutIfNeeded() call on the container view?

Comment: @Helium3, Yes, I tend to remove all my constraints and reset them when a major layout-altering event happens.